# Indenting and JShint issues with extremely large JS files

Tags: javascript, syntax, formatting

I am dealing with 15-20K line long JS files and I noticed that two things were happening

1. when I auto indented a large block at some point the indentation would stop. At first, I thought there was some syntax error in that region but when I isolated that block of code the indentation would work fine
2. JShint would make ludicrous assertions like `'xxx' is defined but not used`. A simple search showed that the variable was being used. I did not perform an exhaustive analysis, but all cases I did look at involved the variable being declared at the top of the page but used much later at the bottom of the page. When I copy/pasted the code block to the top of the page the problem would disappear

As an experiment, I wrote a simple script like this one. It's too long to copy/paste here, but it can easily be created in vim using a macro. It can't be a coincidence that the error happened exactly after the 499'th function, can it? Is this a memory issue? A Plugin setting? An upper limit to the number of functions allowed in JS?

```js
/* Before VIM formatting */
(() => {
var a1 = 1;
var a2 = 2;
var a3 = 3;
/* Repeat 504 times */
var a500 = 500;
var a501 = 501;
var a502 = 502;
var a503 = 503;
var a504 = 504;

function print_a1 (){
console.log (a1);
}
/* Repeat 504 times */

function print_a499 (){
console.log (a499);
}
function print_a500 (){
console.log (a500);
}
function print_a501 (){
console.log (a501);
}
function print_a502 (){
console.log (a501);
}
function print_a503 (){
console.log (a501);
}
function print_a504 (){
console.log (a501);
}
    
});

/* After VIM formatting (gg=G) */
(() => {
    var a1 = 1;
    var a2 = 2;
    var a3 = 3;
    /* Repeat 504 times */
    var a500 = 500;
    var a501 = 501;
    var a502 = 502;
    var a503 = 503;
    var a504 = 504;
    
    function print_a1 (){
      console.log (a1);
    }
    /* Repeat 504 times */
    
    function print_a499 (){
      console.log (a499);
    }
function print_a500 (){
console.log (a500);
}
function print_a501 (){
console.log (a501);
}
function print_a502 (){
console.log (a501);
}
function print_a503 (){
console.log (a501);
}
function print_a504 (){
console.log (a501);
}
    
});
```

Comment: Please, remove that "vim" tag as it is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @romainl The Q has 3 parts and I think parts 1 and 3 are about `vim`. Part 2 is about `JShint` and must be split into a separate question.